# How do I remove the spacing between the NavigationView and the top view? (Profile view)

Tags: swift, swiftui

https://streamable.com/3wtus

I first display a login screen, which has a green background, then the user taps login, and sees the profile view, which has a green unwanted thing at the top.

My goal is to use the NavigationView on my whole screen. You can clearly see that the views are overlapping.

Here is my code for presenting the views:

**ViewRouter**

```
class ViewRouter: ObservableObject {
   let objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<ViewRouter,Never>()

   var currentPage: String = "login" {
      didSet {
          objectWillChange.send(self)
      }
   }
}
```

**MotherView**

```
struct MotherView: View {
   @State var page = "login"
   @ObservedObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter
   @State var user = ""
   @State var pass = ""
   @State var login = false
   @State var signup = false

   var body: some View {
       ZStack {
           LinearGradient(gradient: .init(colors: [Color("1"),Color("2")]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
           if viewRouter.currentPage == "login" {
               Login(login: $login, signup: $signup, user: $user, pass: $pass, viewRouter: viewRouter)

           } else if viewRouter.currentPage == "main" {
               Main()
          }
       }.alert(isPresented: $login) {

        Alert(title: Text(self.user), message: Text(self.pass), dismissButton: .none)

       }.sheet(isPresented: $signup) {

        signUp(signup: self.$signup)
       }
     }
  }
```

**Main**

```
struct Main: View {
   var body: some View {

        TabView {
            Profile()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "1.circle")
                    Text("Profile")

                }.tag(0)

            Text("Leaderboards")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "2.circle")
                    Text("Leaderboards")

                }.tag(1)

            Text("News")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "3.circle")
                    Text("News")
                }.tag(2)
        }
    }
}
```

**Profile**

```
struct Profile: View {
var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
        Text("Profile")
        .navigationBarTitle("Profile", displayMode: .large)
    }
   }
}
```

I have tried to set an offset and padding to the **NavigationView** in the **Profile** struct, but it did not result in anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I can not test my answer. But try this:

```
struct Main: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ...
        } .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you:) Made my day